# How to display pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf

I'm trying to display a pdf file in php, I used:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myiframe {
                width: 600px;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scroller">
            <iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe" src="xml.pdf"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

it works in HTML well, but when I want to use this code into a php file, it displays nothing and only tries to download the pdf file.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: There's no PHP code there. How are you using PHP?

Comment: have u used the file extension as .php?

Comment: Your code is working to me

Comment: See >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Comment: Also try `header("Content-type: application/pdf"); header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf"); @readfile('path\to\filename.pdf');`

Answer (score 43):

There are quite a few options that can be used: (both tested).

Here are two ways.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
@readfile('path\to\filename.pdf');
```

**or:** (note the escaped double-quotes). The same need to be use when assigning a name to it.

```
<?php

echo "<iframe src=\"file.pdf\" width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\"></iframe>";

?>
```

**I.e.**: `name="myiframe" id="myiframe"`

would need to be changed to:

`name=\"myiframe\" id=\"myiframe\"` inside PHP.

Be sure to have a look at: [**this answer on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291823/1415724) for more options on the subject.

**Footnote**: There are known issues when trying to view PDF files in Windows 8. Installing Adobe Acrobat Reader is a better method to view these types of documents if no browser plug-ins are installed.

Comment: How can you do `@readfile()` if you never save it? Where does the path come from?

Answer (score 15):

Try this below code

```
<?php
$file = 'dummy.pdf';
$filename = 'dummy.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: @url  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-open-a-pdf-files-in-web-browser-using-php/

Comment: what if the pdf has a protected password?

Answer (score 4):

Download PDFObject library from https://pdfobject.com/ and check the below code: I hope it will work you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pdf Read</title>
    <style>
          .pdfobject-container { height: 500px;}
          .pdfobject { border: 1px solid #666; }
   </style>
   <script src="pdfobject.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="example1"></div>
        <script>PDFObject.embed("pdfread.pdf", "#example1");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you were to add that using the pdfobject js library frees you from having to check whether the browser supports inline pdf display or not or what pdf library it would use, whether or not it would mess up the pdf display, your answer might hit more likes m8. I like pdfobject.js because it is all the above and gives the same features to all my user despite whatever browser they're using

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to display pdf files from database and we can download it.
$resume is pdf file name which comes from database.
../resume/filename is path of folder where your file is stored.

```
<a href="../resumes/<?php echo $resume; ?>"/><?php echo $resume; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['content'])){
  $content = $_GET['content'];
  $dir = $_GET['dir'];
  header("Content-type:".$content);
  @readfile($dir);
}

$directory = (file_exists("mydir/"))?"mydir/":die("file/directory doesn't exists");// checks directory if existing.
 //the line above is just a one-line if statement (syntax: (conditon)?code here if true : code if false; )
 if($handle = opendir($directory)){ //opens directory if existing.
   while ($file = readdir($handle)) { //assign each file with link <a> tag with GET params
     echo '<a target="_blank" href="?content=application/pdf&dir='.$directory.'">'.$file.'</a>';
}
```

}

if you click the link  a new window will appear with the pdf file

Answer (score 0):

easy if its pdf or img use

```
return (in_Array($file['content-type'], ['image/jpg', 'application/pdf']));
```