# Laravel 5.0 render non public pdf?

Tags: laravel, file, private

I need to display a pdf in my website, but I need to keep it out of the public folder and do some validations before showing it.

I was researching a little and now I know that I have to keep it in a folder like storage. But I don´t know how to retrieve it and render it in the browser.
I know that in recent laravel versions you can use `response()->file()` to achieve this, inside a controller.

But in the documentation there is no reference to that type of response in older versions of laravel. I need to do it in laravel 5.0.

Edit: i need a solution for older laravel versions as i said, specifically for laravel 5.0. I can´t use newer solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - How to access image uploaded in storage within View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)

Answer (score 1):

use plain php, you just need add headers and print file

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");

return response(file_get_contents(storage_path('path to file in storage')));
```

Comment: This gives me almost what i need.
But it throws an error when tries to load the pdf.
At least i get the response and the browser loads the pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you need:

```
$contents = Storage::get('file.jpg');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#basic-usage

Comment: Will this display the pdf with the browser "plugin", with zoom controls and everything?
Thank you.

Comment: No, see the other answer for that or maybe this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040386/how-to-display-pdf-in-php