# Why my return file in php after form send doesn't work?

Tags: php, ajax

```
    <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'info@bpmo-solutions.kz'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return readfile(polychor_file.pdf);         
?>
```

I have a response and all work correct with status 200, so why did I cannot take my file back? I need to show pdf file after the form sent.

Comment: `readfile(polychor_file.pdf)` should throw a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Header:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
@readfile('path\to\filename.pdf');
```

Take a look at the following example:
[How to display PDF in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040386/how-to-display-pdf-in-php/18040563)